# PHP title using $_GET

Tags: php

I have this ugly piece of code for changing title on products.php

I'm setting the title using $_GET.. Here's the code:

```
<?php
    if (empty($products)){
        ?>

        <title>All products - car parts store</title>

        <?php
    } else {
        if ($products == '1'){
            ?>

            <title>New products - car parts store</title> 

            <?php
        } else if ($products == '2'){
            ?>

            <title>Old products - car parts store</title>
        }
    ?>
```

Is there any better way to do this, because $products can be like this $products == 21.. and I don't want to do that many IFs.

Comment: This won't execute. the `}` on the last line, needs to have a `<?php`

Answer (score 4):

```
$id = (isset($_GET['id'])) ? intval($_GET['id']) : 0;
$title = array(
    'All products - car parts store',
    'New products - car parts store',
    'Old products - car parts store'
);
?>
<title><?php echo $title[$id]; ?></title>
```

All I did here was put the titles in an array and then used the value of the $_GET parameter to choose the title we want from the array.

You will notice I made sure that `$id` is always given an integer value and zero if it is not set or a non-integer value is provided. This can be improved upon by explicitly defining array keys and also checking to make sure an array value exists before using it.

Comment: I'd consider explicitly defining the keys here.

Comment: @crush This definitely can be improved upon. I just hoped to show a possible solution.